# SQL sort sub-sets of table

Tags: sql

Given an SQL table with the following format:

| ID | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 12 |

I'm trying to write a request that would return the table sorted by age within each ID, and not for the whole table. For example, the previous table should be sorted this way:

| ID | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 12 |

The ages have been sorted, but only for each subset of IDs.

Comment: Do you have two questions here? Are you first wondering how to return a subset of data? Then how to sort those results? Or rather, are you wanting to return ALL rows, but then sort only a few of them? If the latter, then please provide more sample data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
ORDER BY id, age
```

Answer (score -1):

Select Id, age
From tablename
Order by Id, age should work